# How do I copy or clone a LinkedList-implemented Queue in Java?

Tags: java, queue, clone, cloneable

I have a `Queue` q1, that is implemented as a `LinkedList`, and I want to define a `Queue` q2, that is a separate, but identical identical instance of `Queue` q1.

How do I do that since `Queue` does not implement `Cloneable`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In a one liner:

`new LinkedList<>(myQueue);`

Since `Queue extends Collection`, and collections have a constructor that takes another `Collection`, this is a quick way to do a shallow clone.

Substitute `LinkedList` with your own `Queue` implementation if you wish.

Also, read the javadocs. They have all the answers.

Comment: new LinkedList<MyObject>(myQueue); should do

Comment: You're right, I'm an idiot. Queue extends Collection.

Answer (score 5):

you can use an iterator :

```
Iterator<Integer> it = q1.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())  {
   q2.add(it.next());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If q1 is one of JCF implementations of Queue like ArrayQueue etc are Cloneable you can use

```
    Queue q2 = ((Cloneable)q1).clone();
```

otherwise

```
    Queue q2 = q1.getClass().newInstance();
    for(Object e : q1) {
        q2.add(e);
    }
```